# JS - Stop DIV and add class at position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have three DIV's.

```
#topper
#slider
.nav
```

If the page is scrolled up, the .nav gets the class "fixed" if it reaches the top of the page.

It works nice, but the .nav first covers the .topper. What can I do to stop the .nav at top:50px?

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSieDa/z9k83ajn/

Comment: where is cod you have try?

Comment: Do you want to have margin between #topper and the  top border of the screen?

Comment: @Nameismy The Topper is a line with basic information and should stay always on top. If you scroll down and the .nav reaches the bottom of #topper, it should get position:fixed under the #topper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saaae2a9/)

Your JS can be more concise and flexible:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#slider').outerHeight(false) - $('.topper').outerHeight(false) ) {
            $('.nav').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Replace your code with code above.

Also I changed CSS:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px; //here
}
```

and added

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just changed nav -58 in ur offset and interval

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var $document, didScroll, offset;
    offset = $('.nav').position().top - 58 ;
    $document = $(document);
    didScroll = false;
    $(window).on('scroll touchmove', function() {
      return didScroll = true;
    });
    return setInterval(function() {
      if (didScroll) {

        $('.nav').toggleClass('fixed', $document.scrollTop() > offset);
        return didScroll = false;
      }
    }, 10);
  });

}).call(this);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9k83ajn/7/

Comment: I can't see any effect. The changes you have made only hide the .fixed out of visble area.
The .nav should change from position:relative to position: fixed if top: 58px is reached.

Comment: yea, i got it, let me change

Comment: it works now, ur offset touches the width after 50 px, so i changed the offset -50 , so it reacts before it reaches the top...

Comment: It's near to that I wanted. Only thing is the "Jumping"-Effect if you scroll doesn't look really nice. Perfect would be to scroll down and the .nav just stops at the position under the .topper.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the css  when scroll up on fixed class

$('.fixed').css('top','-90px');

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var $document, didScroll, offset;
    offset = $('.nav').position().top;
    $document = $(document);
    didScroll = false;
    $(window).on('scroll touchmove', function() {
      return didScroll = true;
    });
    return setInterval(function() {
      if (didScroll) {
        $('.nav').toggleClass('fixed', $document.scrollTop() > offset);
        **$('.fixed').css('top','-90px');**
        return didScroll = false;
      }
    }, 250);
  });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: I'm a really noob in JS as you can see....so where this snippets comes into my JS???

Comment: Mhm...not really. If it is set to -90px, the .nav .fixed is out of visible area. 

Setting to 58px brings same effect as before.